# Mvc2 controls and Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, razor

Can i use mvc2 controls with new Razor engine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean all the extension methods (ie. `Html.ActionLink` etc.), yes of course, you'll use `@Html.ActionLink()` in Razor.

If you mean those Webforms like controls: `<mvc:XXX.../>` or `<asp:XXX .../>`: no. These are being rendered by the Webforms ViewEngine and Razor will just output them as HTML.